# GORM - Query one to many association in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm, criteria

I have Course Domain

```
class Course {
    String name

    static hasMany = [categories: Category]
}
```

Category domain class

```
class Category {
    String name 
}
```

so here a Course can have multiple Category.

Now I want to find all the courses which has a Category whose id is say 4

I tried writing HQL query:

```
def courseList = Course.findAll("from Course as c where c.categories.id in (4)")
```

which gives an error.

How to write correct HQL or a proper withCriteria query ?

Comment: Is that a typo or are you really trying to use hasMany and belongsTo on the same side? Just doesn't seem right. If a course hasMany categories then it cannot belongTo a category.

Comment: @ uchamp: It was type error, updated my question..

Answer (score 4):

You can use withCriteria query:

```
Course.withCriteria { 
    categories { 
        eq 'id', new Long(4)
    }
}
```